# Does anything in the Area or Removable rules indicate that held/worn objects are not subject to Area attacks?

Tags: equipment, area-of-effect, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, content-identification

I have this vague memory that in 2E M&M, it was specifically indicated that, in an Area Attack, Devices and Equipment were not affected, but rather had to be targeted specifically. I can't find similar text in 3E (actually, I haven't found the 2E text, either). It would make some sense, so as to avoid players having to roll a dozen different checks if they have multiple Devices and Equipment on their person when hit with a fireball, but I would prefer to have actual rules text to refer to if my players ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still have no answer for 3e, but I did find [a comment from the designer, Steve Kenson, in the Official Rules Questions section of the old Atomic Think Tank forums addressing Area effects and Devices](https://web.archive.org/web/20140722221718/http://www.atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?t=12001).

> **On a related question, what happens when someone is in an area effect and has devices? Since the rules are mum on the subject, I assume the answer usually is "nothing".**
>
> Also correct.

Presumably, the same rules apply for 3E. And, of course, making a player roll a save for their power armor or assault rifle when caught in an explosion is a reasonable case for a Hero Point for the unforeseen Complication.